# Keep image in ratio and not allow to expand outside of container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Feel like I have explored every option on this and without resulting in a lot of javascript work I wanted to see if there was another way around this.

I have a main container that is 100vh and fixed. The aim for this client is to not allow any scrolling. Inside this container I have a number of image layouts, the images need to remain the same ratio and sizing no matter what width / height the browser.

Here is 2 example layouts, the black boxes being images:

[image]

[image]

I thought it was simple at first, just give the images a width percentage and they will be responsive however they also need to respond to the height.

An example site is here: http://geordiewood.com/projects/meetka/2

If you resize the browser you can see the images remaining in ratio to the broswer spacing around them etc. Inspecting the elements I can see they have dynamicly adjusting heights and width but im looking for a purely css way if possible?

Example html markup:

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="img1.png/><img src="img1.png/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use `max-width` and `max-height`, something along those lines: https://jsfiddle.net/1o9vd4h9/

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Read these docs I think they may help